# How to inject SharedPreferences dependency with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, riverpod

I want to inject a SharedPreferences instance in one of my datasources with the method SharedPreferences.getInstance() but i'm having difficulty because getInstance() returns a Future. Here's my provider file:

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/features/shopping_list/data/datasources/item_local_data_source.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/features/shopping_list/data/repositories/item_repository_impl.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/features/shopping_list/domain/repositories/item_repository.dart';
import 'item_list_state.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/core/usecases/usecases.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/features/shopping_list/domain/usecases/cache_items_list.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/features/shopping_list/domain/usecases/get_items_list.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/features/shopping_list/presentation/logic/item_list/item_list_state.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/features/shopping_list/domain/entities/ingredient.dart';

part 'item_list_state_notifier.dart';

final sharedPreferencesProvider = Provider(
    (ref) => SharedPreferences.getInstance()
);

final _localDataSourceProvider = Provider<ItemLocalDataSource>(
    (ref) =>
         ItemLocalDataSourceImpl(sharedPreferences: ref.watch(sharedPreferencesProvider))

);

final _itemRepositoryProvider = Provider<ItemRepository>(
    (ref) => ItemRepositoryImpl(localDataSource: ref.watch(_localDataSourceProvider))
);

final _getItemsListProvider =
    Provider<GetItemsList>((ref) => GetItemsList(ref.watch(_itemRepositoryProvider)));

final _cacheItemsListProvider = 
    Provider<CacheItemsList>(
        (ref) => CacheItemsList(ref.watch(_itemRepositoryProvider))
    );

final itemListNotifierProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<ItemListNotifier, ItemListState>((ref) =>
        ItemListNotifier(
            getItemsList: ref.watch(_getItemsListProvider),
            cacheItemsList: ref.watch(_cacheItemsListProvider)));
```

I tried overriding the sharedPreferencesProvider in the ProviderScope but it didn't help.

What's the best way to instanciate SharedPreferences using Riverpod?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FutureProvider` for that, e.g.:

```
final configProvider = FutureProvider<Configuration>((ref) async {
  final content = json.decode(
    await rootBundle.loadString('assets/configurations.json'),
  ) as Map<String, Object?>;

  return Configuration.fromJson(content);
});
```

So in your case, it would be something like this:

```
final configProvider = FutureProvider<SharedPreferences>((ref) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  return prefs;
});
```

More info: https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/FutureProvider-class.html

Comment: I see, but i don't understand how to use the FutureProvider to instanciate my datasource class which takes a SharedPreferences instance in its constructor. In the documentation it shows an example on how to use it in the UI but that's not what i want to do.

Comment: You can try to combine providers, e.g. create a provider for your Datasource class and inside the init code, wait for the SharedPreferences provider to init. Something like this: https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers#combining-providers